# Horizontal view of data in the listview windows form control

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have not been able to find the google solution, I hope here than it can help me quickly.

I want my data to be displayed below each other and scrollable to the right.

I have included these controls so far, a view from the designer attached:

```
 'ListView1 from Designer
        '
        Me.ListView1.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None
        Me.ListView1.HideSelection = False
        Me.ListView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(26, 184)
        Me.ListView1.Name = "ListView1"
        Me.ListView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(368, 49)
        Me.ListView1.TabIndex = 27
        Me.ListView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = False
        Me.ListView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details
        Me.ListView1.Columns.Clear()
        Me.ListView1.Columns.Add("").Width = -2
```

what do i miss in order for my data to appear below each other and scroll to the right(vertical to scroll)?
so I would like the data to be displayed below and not in the next row and then scroll vertically.

[image]
like in the picture that data is showing me ..

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's already being displayed like you're saying.  One record per line, every field in each record displayed from left to right.  Is that not it?  Please update your question to make your requirements clearer.

Comment: @rory.ap so I would like the data to be displayed below and not in the next row and then scroll vertically

Comment: _displayed below and not in the next row_ very unclear. Do you mean multiline fields? - Can you show waht yopu want also?

Comment: @TaW yes to the line of fields, (one below the other)

Comment: @Michael You repeated what you already said.  That doesn't make any sense.  Please *clarify your requirements*.

Comment: What is the __View mode__ of the LV? It should be `Details`. (don't forget to add at least one column!)

Comment: I added an image so I would like the data to be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ListView`, Set `View` to `Details` and set `HeaderStyle` to `None`. Note, that you must add a column to the `ListView` Control. Set the column `Width` to `-1`, so that the column spans the whole control.

This is how this would look from code, but you can also do the setup in the form designer.

```
// Setup listview appearance
listView1.Columns.Clear();
listView1.Columns.Add("");
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;


// Add items
listView1.Items.Add("Aber Aber aber");
listView1.Items.Add("Kunde mit ID 1234 ist nicht in der Datenbank enthalten");
listView1.Items.Add("Stackoverflow rulez");

// Adapt widht of column
listView1.Columns[0].Width = -1;
```

Comment: it shows me right now but the text is not visible all over, how can i correct it? I corrected the question

Comment: @Michael You need to set Width to -1 again after adding items to adapt the width of the column to the actual content. I have updated the answer.

Comment: If you use -1, if the text is wider than the listview. there will be a horizontal scrollbar. If you use -2 instead of -1, the content will be trimmed to fit the width of the control. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.columnheader.width